# Correct way of writing down the attribute list of tuples of floats?

Tags: python, tuples, uml

I'm new to UML modeling and I need to write down the attribute of a class that is a list of tuples of floats. How detailed does the attribute section need to be? Here is a code sample for further explanation:

```
# floats
x1 = 1.0
y1 = 1.0

x2 = 1.1
y2 = 1.1

x3 = 1.2
y3 = 1.2

# tuples of floats
tup1 = (x1,y1)
tup2 = (x2,y2)
tup3 = (x3,y3)

# list of tuples of floats / attribute of my class
points = [tup1,tup2,tup3]
```

The tuples represent points in 2d-space (x- and y-coordinate). What would the attribute of "points" look like?

I thought of different possibilities, but I'm not really satisfied with them:

points : tuple[2..*]

points : float[2..*][2]

I'm lost! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: start by modelling the Point as a class, then associate your class to the Point class.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @ Geert Bellekens solved your point, but you can try a model closest to your code.

Tuple does not exist in UML.

The solution is to define a DataType containing two values.

The difference between DataType and a Class is that a DataType does not have "id", two DataType with the same value are equivalent.

If you have a class Person with name, and age, two instances with the same name and the same age are different: there "ids" are different.

In the schema, Point properties are public to avoid complexity and because this is a DataType but this is "my" choice.

[image: points]